# Is it possible to specify function sub directories / paths?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I'm writing my first azure function project in node.js. I have my project directory, in which exists the `host.json` and local settings files. As far as I understand it, my individual function folders, in which `function.json` and my function code exists, must reside as a sibling to the `hosts.json` file. So, project folders must look something like ...

```
project-root/
  package.json
  host.json
  function-a/
    function.json
    index.js
  function-b/
    function.json
    index.js
```

But, is it possible to have a project structure with those function folders nested deeper? Something like the following, perhaps ...

```
project-root/
  package.json
  host.json
  src/
    function-a/
      function.json
      index.js
    function-b/
      function.json
      index.js
```

This might be useful if I were to be using TypeScript and would need to the function host to execute out of a `dist` folder, like below ...

```
project-root/
  package.json
  host.json
  src/
    function-a/
      function.json
      index.js
    function-b/
      function.json
      index.js
  dist/
    function-a/
    function-b/
```

I can't seem to get the function host to look into nested directories, though.

Is this possible?

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't supported as of today. There is a feature request for this on [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/18772849-folders-for-organizing-functions-and-a-treeview-fu) and was discussed in this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2194) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Not currently supported. Here is uservoice for the request ...

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/18772849-folders-for-organizing-functions-and-a-treeview-fu